# Пропадает background на Safari 12

Tags: css, safari

Ситуация следующая: при тесте сайта на iPhone 6, после загрузки всей страницы фон становится белым, а должен быть градиент. Происходит это через 1-3 секунды после загрузки.
Использовался Safari 12.
Проект собирается на Gulp с использованием Autoprefixer, так что вряд ли с префиксами проблемы..
Что это может быть ?

Вот таким образом прописан фон, в остальных браузерах, в том числе на мобильных устройствах, все работает нормально, фон не пропадает.

```css
    body {
    background: linear-gradient(#1d0620, #4b1053);
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте такой вариант - background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1d0620, #4b1053);

Comment: попробовал, не помогает. помогло прописать обычный background-color. но вот градиент никак не хочет ложится

Comment: Еще такой вариант попробуйте - background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1d0620 0%,#4b1053 100%);

Comment: без изменений, такое ощущение, будто где-то этот градиент перебивается, потому что, изначально он виден, но спустя 1-3 секунды белый фон

Comment: чтобы это проверить добавьте !important;

Comment: добавил, результат нулевой.